# How to use a value received from one service in another service within the same Angular 6 component?

Tags: javascript, angular

The following component's code is from an Angular 6 web application that I am creating. The app displays a table with CRUD functionality. I have an Angular service called GetDBValuesService that is connected to a database and uses DBValues() to retrieve an array of arrays (each inner array contains the values of a given row in the database). My code then collects rows whose 'Number' attribute is equal to 10. These rows are then used by my EventEmitter dataItems, which allows them to be displayed in my web page's CRUD table.

I have created another Angular service called DataService that receives an integer value from another component and sends that value to the shown component (after being subscribed to). I subscribed to this service in the following code and let an instance of gotdata (a public var declared in this component) receive the service's value. However, when I try to use this instance outside of that subscription (to replace the hardcoded 10 described above), this.gotdata is undefined.

How can I modify my code so that I can use the value given by the DataService service in the GetDBValuesService service? Currently, the below code does work due to the hardcoded 10, but does not if I remove that line. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

**This is the portion of my CRUD component:**

```
refresh = () => {
    this.DataService.DataID$.subscribe((data) => {
        this.gotdata = data;
        console.log(this.gotdata); //10 (value from console)
    });
    console.log(this.gotdata); //undefined (value from console)
    this.gotdata = 10; //hardcoded value allows further functionality, will be removed when this.gotdata retains its value from the above subscription
    if (this.gotdata != null) {
        this.GetDBValuesService.DBValues().subscribe((result) => {
            var a = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if (result[i].Number == this.gotdata) {
                    this.info[a] = result[i];
                    a = a + 1;
                }
            }
            this.dataItems.next(this.info); //sets rows to be displayed in the web page's table (used by component's HTML file)
        });
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.gotdata` is undefined because the data is not resolved yet.

```
refresh = () => {
this.DataService.DataID$.subscribe((data) => {
    this.gotdata = data;
    console.log(this.gotdata); //10 (value from console)

    if (this.gotdata != null) {
        this.GetDBValuesService.DBValues().subscribe((result) => {
            var a = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                if (result[i].Number == this.gotdata) {
                    this.info[a] = result[i];
                    a = a + 1;
                }
            }
            this.dataItems.next(this.info); //sets rows to be displayed in the web page's table (used by component's HTML file)
        });
   }}
});
```

Or you can put it inside subscription on complete callback:

```
this.service.subscribe((data) => {
    // code here
},
(error) => console.error(error),
() => {
    // do stuff.
});
```

Comment: Not only it isn’t resolved yet, but queued tasks are processed after the main thread is task-free

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, at the time when you are calling the `console.log(...)` and the code below, data from the `dataID$`observable are still on way to you. ( [Why do u need to work with observables?](http://reactivex.io/intro.html))

The best approach for this would to be use the RXJS `switchMap` operator ([what is switchMap?](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)). Because as I see you want to subscribe to the first `observable` and after that subscribe to another `observable`. So it can be done this way:

```
refresh = () => {
    this.DataService.DataID$.pipe(switchMap(data: any) => {
        if (data) {
            this.gotdata = data;
            return this.GetDBValuesService.DBValues();
        } else {
            return of(null); // if 'data' are null, return "empty" observable
        }
    })).subscribe((result: any) => {
        if (!result) {
            return; // return if 'result' is null (so the code bellow won't be executed)
        }
        var a = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i].Number == this.gotdata) {
                this.info[a] = result[i];
                a = a + 1;
            }
        }
        this.dataItems.next(this.info);
    });
```

Comment: Trying to use this code returns error: 'Cannot find name data'

Comment: which line is the error pointing ? Or also can you share more code, atleast the `DataService.DataID$` observable